# Evulating line integral (vector calculus)

Tags: calculus

Consider the vector fields

$F(x, y) = (1 + y)i + (1 − x)j,
$

For vector field F, determine if it is conservative and evaluate
its line integral along the curve C, where C is the segment of the curve $y = x^
2$
,
starting at $(0, 0)$ and terminating at $(1, 1)$.

What i tried

F is not conservative since $Q_{x}=-1$ while $P_{y}=1$

For the second part of the question, i tried using Green theorem to evaluate the line integral, getting

$$\int_{0} ^1\int_0 ^{x^2} -2\,dy\,dx$$

However i don't seem to get the right answer. Can Green theorem be used in this case? It seems that Green theorem seem to work in some cases but it dosent work in other cases. And how do i approach this problem if Green theorem does not work.Could i use the fundamental theorem of line integral Could anyone explain. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Green's theorem can only be used for evaluating integrals along a closed loop $C$, which is not the case here. Instead parameterize by $y=x^2$ by $x(t)=t$ and $y(t)=t^2$.

We seek the value of the following integral

$$\int^1_0F(\langle t,t^2\rangle)\cdot\langle1,2t\rangle dt=\int^1_0\langle 1+t^2,1-t\rangle\cdot\langle1,2t\rangle dt=\int^1_01+2t-t^2 dt=\frac{5}{3}$$

Comment: How do u tell whether a curve C has a closed loop?

Comment: You should be able to glean that information from the problem statement. For example, your problem tells us that you are starting at the point (0,0) and following the curve until the point (1,1). Clearly it has distinct starting and ending points.